# Generating x,y coordinates for an edge detection of image

Tags: image-processing

i have a photo and I want to obtain the coordinates in a table form of its edge so that I could input the data into Autodesk Inventor

May I know how I can do it

[image]

Comment: The edges of the photo? They'd be {0,0}, {0,1}, {1,1}, {1,0} in ImageScaled values... Do you mean the outline of the shoe in the photo?

Answer (score 12):

I am not familiar with Autodesk Inventor but here are 2 ways to generate x,y coordinates from an edge detection of your image:

## to extract a list of edge coordinates

```
edgeCoordinates = PixelValuePositions[
    EdgeDetect[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBKot.jpg"]], 1];
```

---

```
Graphics[Point[edgeCoordinates]]
```

[image]

---

you can also get points manually using:

<kbd>Right Click</kbd>  `Get Coordinates`

[image]

---

when you have clicked the outline in orange dots,

copy and paste the coordinates into an empty cell as a list

[image]

Comment: I wonder  why the downvotes ...

Comment: @ Dr.belisarius I wish they would let me know why? so I could fix, improve or delete my answer. Perhaps I am missing something trivial?

Comment: Didn't realize it was getting downvotes (I upvoted). It seems to be a reasonable answer so don't delete it.