# How to extract the edges in this image?

Tags: image-processing

The question derive from [this place](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/106286/generating-x-y-coordinates-for-an-edge-detection-of-image#106287).And as for its first current answer,I have some place not really satisfied like

[image]

And the `EdgeDetect` have its limitation to improve it.
The second method is by Image-Tool(<kbd>Right Click</kbd> then `Get Coordinates`),I just don't like using Image-Tool to make too much point,but wanna seek a more smart method to do such thing.Due to that question have been voted to closed,I have to take a new post to discuss it sequentially.This is origional image is

[image: img]

I have a try it by `LocalAdaptiveBinarize`

```
LocalAdaptiveBinarize[img, 10]
```

[image]

I feel the direction is right, but I don't know how to make the next step to extract the salient edge(cleanup those noise).And a edge like this is expected to me

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that your question was [answered before](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/106287/27951), and quite thoroughly. Can you specify why the previous answer doesn't work for you?

Comment: @MarcoB Thinks for your concern with this question.I just don't like using Image-Tool to make too much point,but wanna seek a more smart method to do such thing.

Comment: Please state very clearly *within the post itself* (not comments) why the previous answer is not acceptable.  Otherwise this looks like re-posting an existing question.  I don't understand what you mean by "Image-Tool".

Comment: @Szabolcs I have update it.If there are still something inappropriate you tell me,I'll appreciate you.

Comment: The first method in the answer does not use the Get Coordinates tool and it is fully automatic.

Comment: Ok.There are a lot of edges in there. Which one do you want? (Update the question!)

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Glad to see you,I have a new update to express what I expect.

Comment: Are you sure it is worth the work? There are a lot of different textures and colors in there.